# How can I avoid prerelease versions in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, pubspec

Because null safety in flutter is relatively new, I had to depend on some prerelease versions.
However for some packages I would like to use the stable version.
The problem is: flutter don't let me use version `1.0.0` of `hive_generator`. It always selects `0.9.0-nullsafety.0`.

```yaml
dev_dependencies:
  hive_generator: 1.0.0
```

```
Because every version of fast_i18n from git depends on build ^2.0.0 and hive_generator >=0.9.0-nullsafety.0 depends on build ^1.5.2, fast_i18n from git is incompatible with hive_generator >=0.9.0-nullsafety.0.
So, because ikus_app depends on both fast_i18n from git and hive_generator 1.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because ikus_app depends on both fast_i18n from git and hive_generator 1.0.0, version solving failed.)
```

**Edit 1:**

It seems that flutter prefers prereleases when prereleases are in dependency graph:

https://dart.dev/tools/pub/publishing#publishing-prereleases

> Note: If a stable package in the dependency graph depends on a prerelease,
> then pub chooses that prerelease instead of a stable release.

Is there anyway to opt-out one package?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use the git version of `hive_generator`, because it must depend on `build ^2.0.0`.

I forgot that `hive_generator 1.0.0` still depends on `build ^1.5.2`.

`hive_generator >=0.9.0-nullsafety.0` is a display bug I think.